# jQuery Input Event does not Fire if Input is Empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a jQuery event handler that reacts to every change in an:

```
<input id="myId" type="text" />
```

element:

```
$("#myId").bind('input', function (e) {    
        // Do Stuff
    });
```

This works perfectly, except when the input in `#myId` is empty (e.g. there was just 1 character in the input box, and I remove it with <kbd>Backspace</kbd>).  If the input has become empty, the event does not fire.  If I then enter a character, the event fires.

Is this a known issue?  Am I doing something wrong?  Any way to get an event when the input goes empty?

**Update**

The event does not fire AT ALL when <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is entered, at least in IE9.

Comment: When is the event supposed to be fired? Can't you use `keyup` event?

Comment: The oninput event doesn't seem to be widely used but it appears to exist: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.oninput

Comment: FYI, `input` event doesn't work in IE6,7,8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as far as I know, "input" is not the event you want to use. Since "input" is analogous to "change", it tends to produce a bad result when your string approaches 0 chars, use `keyup` instead

```
$("input#myId").bind('keyup', function (e) {    
    // Do Stuff
});
```

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I don't think you can say keyup is "the event you want to use" because input, unlike keyup, detects ANY input, as in cuts & pastes with the mouse. What we have here is simply that firefox and IE disagree on whether a backspace or delete should count as "input". I can see both sides... My guess is that Eric J. really wants an on change event that'd fire without waiting until the element loses focus like the regular change event does. I dunno what the answer to that question is.