# backSpace not firing the keyup event in android mobile

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, backbone.js, marionette

This is the first time,I am working on `mobile Apps`.`keyUp` event not firing If I press `backspace` button.

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33Snz/13/) for reference.

Initially user entered `23` and then user deleted `3` using backspace button.While entering `23` event firing but while delete time event not firing.

I am using `device : motorola motog,Android Version:4.4.2`.

How can I fix this,can anyone help me with an example code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is somewhere Chrome stopped firing keypress events for "backspace" since Android 4.4. This has been problematic in many webview based apps to catch required events. There is a small relief from this by using the `input` event that fires whenever user types something, pastes something, or taps on ".com" button in the keyboard, etc.

It is best to rely on `input` event if you are looking only to capture changes to the input. It is not useful if you want to do preventing default actions.

For your case, I think it should fit. But beware, of the support for this event for earlier than Android 4 version.

Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/aravindbaskaran/33Snz/24/

Comment: Sorry,I didn't seen your message I found solution that day itself,when I post a question.I forgot to post the answer. anyhow what you said that's right.I am also using `input` event.It's working charm.

Comment: Keep in mind that an empty input will result in the input event not firing! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004581/jquery-input-event-does-not-fire-if-input-is-empty

Answer (score 2):

As solution, you could avoid using 'input' event, as mentioned @aravind.
The problem is 'input' event does not work with <=ie9 and some mobile opera devices. Of course you could use browsers support detection, for example by [modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/pull/1055) or simple [snippet](https://github.com/modernizr/modernizr/issues/210) and use supporting keyUp/input event.

On the other hand you could use all events together and browser will decide which one it will use, by itself. The problem is - in this case callback function will be calling twice at modern browsers which support both events.

Workaround is to use debounce function to prevent double calling.

```
$('.parent').on('change keydown input', _.debounce(function() {
    // whatever
}, 0));
```

Note that I'm using keydown event instead of keyup because I set delay only 0 milliseconds, so keyup will be call much later and _.debounce doesn't could help.